# First Character on TextView

Tags: java, android

I have a listview and inside it is a texview. Sometimes only the first character is displayed. And when I refresh the view, the whole word appears. Has anyone experience this? How do I fix this bug? Thanks in advance

Here is my code:

```
ListView tasksList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.tasks_list);
tasksListAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, tasksListItems, R.layout.advanced_view_row,
        new String[] {LIST_ADAPTER_APPLICATION_ICON, LIST_ADAPTER_KEY_NAME, LIST_ADAPTER_KEY_RECEIVED, LIST_ADAPTER_KEY_SENT}, 
        new int[] {R.id.application_icon, R.id.process_name, R.id.received, R.id.sent}
)
{
    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).
            inflate(R.layout.advanced_view_row, parent, false);
        }

        HashMap<String, Object> item = (HashMap<String, Object>)this.getItem(position);

        ((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.application_icon)).setImageDrawable((Drawable) item.get(LIST_ADAPTER_APPLICATION_ICON));
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.process_name)).setText((String) item.get(LIST_ADAPTER_KEY_NAME));
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.received)).setText((String) item.get(LIST_ADAPTER_KEY_RECEIVED));
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sent)).setText((String) item.get(LIST_ADAPTER_KEY_SENT));

        return convertView;
    };
};
tasksList.setAdapter(tasksListAdapter);


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:paddingTop="5dip"
    android:paddingBottom="5dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <TableRow>
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/status"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.01"/> 
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/application_icon"
            android:layout_width="32dip"
            android:layout_height="32dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.09"/> 
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/process_name"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"/>
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/received"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:gravity="right"/>
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/sent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:gravity="right"/>
    </TableRow>    
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Can you add some code from the list initialization and your adapter?

Comment: show the code, from that we can find mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change layout_width of **TextView** with id=**application_icon** to 0dip (instead of 32dip).

In which TextView you have only one character displayed?

Comment: Thanks! I will try that. On R.id.process_name I am having problems with

Comment: Does it help? And why are using TableLayout? I think, LinearLayout is more prefferable.